# Why LRU doesn't suffer Belady's Anomaly?

Tags: operating-system, theory

I have a question about page replacement algorithms. FIFO suffers from [Belady's Anomaly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belady%27s_anomaly) but LRU doesn't. Does anyone know why LRU doesn't suffer? I've been searching for the reason on the internet but no luck.

Comment: Being a purely technical question, this belongs to StackOverflow (please don't repost it there - it will be automigrated if enough people vote to close it here).

Answer (score 10):

Because LRU is a stacking algorithm, and using k frames will always be a subset of k + n frames for LRU. Thus, any page-faults that may occur for k + n frames will also occur for k frames, which in turn means that LRU doesn't suffer Belady's anomaly.

Comment: My understanding is that, in LRU, the elements in the stack is ordered by most recently used, which means the top k elements in a (k+n)-size stack are identical as the k elements in k-size stack.

Comment: @RafaelJ looks to me like you're saying the same thing as Caspar is saying, maybe a bit more clearly.  I think this is a good explanation.

Comment: @DonHatch, yes I am. I didn't understand at the beginning, so I left my version if it here. Maybe it could help someone?

Answer (score 5):

Because FIFO assumes that the mere fact that a page has been occupying memory for a long time that it is the safest to replace, where in reality that simply isn't the case.  Rather, where FIFO fails is that statistically, if a page has been called frequently, it's more likely to be called again than another page which has been called recently.  In other words, frequency is a far better determiner of page loading than age.

Comment: You are not answering the question.

Answer (score 5):

Similar to Caspar's answer, however I found the explanation from my textbook (slightly edited) to be a bit more clear.

> [*LRU belongs*] to a class of page-replacement algorithms, called stack algorithms, [*which*] can never exhibit Belady’s anomaly.
>
> A stack algorithm is an algorithm for which it can be shown that the set of pages in memory for N frames is always a subset of the set of pages that would be in memory with N + 1 frames. [*Therefore an additional frame will never cause an additional page fault.*]
>
> For LRU replacement, the set of pages in memory would be the N most recently referenced pages. If the number of frames is increased, these N pages will still be the most recently referenced and so will still be in memory.

Silberschatz, A., Galvin, P. B., & Gagne, G. (2014). Operating System Concepts (9th ed.). Singapore: Wiley.